# Test if points are within rectangles

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have some data points and can easily plot them in a figure in MATLAB.

I need to find out which data points are located inside some rectangular areas, as can be seen in the attached picture. In this picture, black dots represent my data points and red rectangles represent mentioned areas.

How can I search through my data points and see whether or not they belong to any of the rectangles? I need to have a list of all members (data points) for each rectangle.

**Sample data points and rectangles:**

[image: Sample data points and rectangles]

Comment: use "inpolygon" function.

Comment: @Ozcan thanks alot. That's what I wanted! I couldn't even guess such a function exists!

Comment: You can check the functions list of MATLAB in here:  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/functionlist.html

Comment: @Ozcan I always do and I'm kind of master in MATLAB but this function is awesome. Never seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ozcan said in the comments, [`inpolygon`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) is the way to go. Here's a quick demo, see comments for details:

```
% Create 4 random rectangles, defined by their x and y coords in rectX and rectY.
% Each column defines a different rectangle.
sizes = randi([5,10], 2, 4)./10;
rectX = randi([1,5], 1, 4);   rectX = [rectX; rectX; rectX + sizes(1,:); rectX + sizes(1,:)];
rectY = randi([1,5], 1, 4);   rectY = [rectY; rectY + sizes(2,:); rectY + sizes(2,:); rectY];
% Create a random set of 1000 points for testing
points = [rand(1000, 1)*range(rectX(:))+min(rectX(:)), rand(1000, 1)*range(rectY(:))+min(rectY(:))];
% Set up logical matrix of test results
inrect = logical(zeros(size(points,1), size(rectX,2)));
% Plot the rectangles using patch
    figure;
patch(rectX,rectY,'red')
% Hold on and plot all of the points as black dots
hold on; 
plot(points(:,1),points(:,2),'.k');
% Loop through each rectangle, testing the points
for r = 1:size(rectX, 2)
    % Test points using inpolygon, store results to inrect matrix
    inrect(:,r) = inpolygon(points(:,1), points(:,2), rectX(:,r), rectY(:,r));
end
% Plot all points which are in any rectangle as blue circles
plot(points(any(inrect,2), 1), points(any(inrect,2), 2), 'bo');
```

Result:

[image: plot]

---

Note you now have the logical matrix `inrect`, which is true (in one column per rectangle, one row per point) when the point is within a rectangle. The code above uses the `any` operator for plotting when the point is in *any* of the rectangles.